# Rabbitmq TTL expired messages (through queue policy) aren't removed

Tags: rabbitmq, ttl, dead-letter

I want to have messages that end up in a Dead Letter Queue automatically deleted after a certain period of time.

My understanding of [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats) is that messages that are in the head of the queue will be automatically deleted when they expire ( `TTL`).

I have setup a `message-ttl` policy with value of 10 seconds on a dead letter queue, but messages that end up here aren't deleted. The policy is visible on the queue, so it is applied. There are no consumers added to this queue.

This is the policy:

[image]

Why don't the messages get deleted after 10 seconds?

Comment: Note that "DLX" stands for "Dead Letter Exchange", not "Dead Letter Queue". That's important, because exchanges don't hold messages, only queues do.

Comment: @IMSoP You're right, I'll remove that from the question.